# sharepoint 2013 - use CSOM to change the view sort column

Tags: sharepoint, csom

I have a list, in its default view (all item), it is sorting by the ID by default, I need to use CSOM to change sort column to 'Title' column, how should I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to set View sorting via CSOM:

```
var pagesList = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Pages");
var view = pagesList.DefaultView;
view.ViewQuery = CreateOrder("Title",true);
view.Update();
ctx.ExecuteQuery();


public static string CreateOrder(string fieldName, bool ascending)
{
    return string.Format("<OrderBy><FieldRef Name=\"{0}\" Ascending=\"{1}\" /></OrderBy>", fieldName, ascending ? "TRUE" : "FALSE"); 
}
```